# SVN With Two-Factor Authentication

Tags: security, svn, authentication

I work at an organization with stringent security requirements, sometimes excessively so. My project team is trying to create an SVN repository, and we are having difficulties setting one up to comply with both our needs and our security requirements.

Our IT department requires us to authenticate ourselves with two-factor authentication. Each developer has an RSA token that must be used to log in to the repository host machines via SSH. The value displayed on the token changes once per minute and each value can be used only once.

The developers require the capability to store passwords. This prevents us from using `svn+ssh` to log in to the repository. Since the RSA token changes once a minute, we can't store the SSH passwords. Worse, the RSA token would reduce us to one SVN operation each minute. This is flatly unacceptable, especially since we have scripts that chain multiple SVN operations together.

We attempted to compromise by opening an SSH tunnel with port forwarding. We would open up a tunnel using `ssh user@hostmachine -L 3690:localhost:3690` to forward all SVN requests on our local machine to the secure machine, where an `svnserve` process was running. This meant we could log in with two-factor authentication, and then use a separate SVN username and password (which could be stored) with our utilities.

Unfortunately, we noticed that we didn't need the tunnel; port 3690 was available to any computer for whom the hostname was visible. This is unacceptable to IT, and our sysadmin thinks that `svnserve` is the problem, so she is wondering if we have to go back to `svn+ssh`.

Is there any solution that works? Is our sysadmin correct? Is there an option on `svnserve` that will force it to listen only to traffic from localhost?

Comment: ServerFault would be better for this, I guess.

Comment: Is there an easy way to move it?

Comment: I just flagged it as "belongs in serverfault". A moderator will take a look at this and send it there if it deems appropiate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

`svnserve -dr /my/repo --listen-host 127.0.0.1`

This way the service will only listen on the loopback interface.  When you connect with ssh use:

`ssh -L3690:127.0.0.1:3690 user@svnserver.mycompany.com`

also see:

```
vince@f12 ~ > svnserve --help
usage: svnserve [-d | -i | -t | -X] [options]

Valid options:
  -d [--daemon]            : daemon mode
  -i [--inetd]             : inetd mode
  -t [--tunnel]            : tunnel mode
  -X [--listen-once]       : listen-once mode (useful for debugging)
  -r [--root] ARG          : root of directory to serve
  -R [--read-only]         : force read only, overriding repository config file
  --config-file ARG        : read configuration from file ARG
  --listen-port ARG        : listen port
                             [mode: daemon, listen-once]
  --listen-host ARG        : listen hostname or IP address
                             [mode: daemon, listen-once]
  -T [--threads]           : use threads instead of fork [mode: daemon]
  --foreground             : run in foreground (useful for debugging)
                             [mode: daemon]
  --log-file ARG           : svnserve log file
  --pid-file ARG           : write server process ID to file ARG
                             [mode: daemon, listen-once]
  --tunnel-user ARG        : tunnel username (default is current uid's name)
                             [mode: tunnel]
  -h [--help]              : display this help
  --version                : show program version information
```

Answer (score 0):

svnserve might have options to only listen on localhost, but this sounds like a firewall configuration issue.

If port 3690 isn't meant to accessible externally, it should be blocked by the firewall.  It shouldn't matter whether svnserve or anything else is listening on that port.  svnserve can then continue to listen on 3690, but will only receive connections from localhost because others are blocked by the firewall.